# Equinox config.ini generated

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, equinox

I've got some osgi plugin development going on. I've created a launch configuration in my eclipse IDE, which adds all required bundles to my runtime. Is there any possibilty to export/convert the eclipse launch config to a config.ini which I can use on my standalone equinox env?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try "New -> Other -> Plug-in Development -> Product Configuration".  You can initialize the content based on your launch configuration.

You can then export the product which will produce a standalone product that you can run.  Just watch out for [bug 278598](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=278598)